# How to create a subfolder inside controller and view folders in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to create a folder named 'schoollevel' inside controller and view folder to create a separate module containing login function and profile views to provide another login functionality for some users. The 'schoollevel' contains all the files for login and profile view. Can anyone suggest how to do this ? I want the control to go to the separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

Its Easy to create folder in controller and view in codeigniter.

Folder name : school

1.create a login controller

```
 application->controller->school->Login.php
```

2. create a login view

   ```
   application->view->school->login.php
   ```

Now, How to call view file

Inside login controller in the `index()` function add

this to call `login.php` view

```
$this->load->view('school/login');
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: When I am creating a folder `schoollevel`, and loading the view file its showing a error like this `Unable to load the requested file: frontend/schoollevel/student_result_view.php`

Comment: a frontend is coming in this

Comment: @Webdeveloper Try like this $this->load->view('schoollevel/student_result_view');

Comment: Maybe beacause you  added another dir called frontend so if you need to load that view it should be like this `$this->load->view('frontend/schoollevel/student_result_view');` .. supposingly that your view folder structure is like this `views/frontend/schoollevel/blahblah_view.php`

Comment: No schoollevel is another separate folder outside frontend...Control is automatically going inside frontend. I dnt want it to go like that. It should go like this `$this->load->view('schoollevel/student_result_view');`